# Why did the engineers give a map to their weapons of mass destruction?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

In [*Prometheus*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/) they are given a map,

[image]

Ordinarily you would think that at the time they would be giving the map to their position of where the Engineers originated from. So why was the map to the weapons of mass destruction and not to the origin of the Engineers?

Comment: You're ascribing modern Western social conversational conventions to an alien race? If you ask an alien where they've come from, they could just as easily tell you the name of the last place they'd been.

Comment: @Valorum, so why did they make a map to the WOMD

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/what-is-the-real-purpose-of-the-star-map-in-prometheus

Comment: @fez, sorry , that means nothing to me

Comment: @KyloRen - **Human** -   "*Hi, Where do you come from?*". **Alien** - "*Here is where we've **just** come from"*

Comment: I'll put this in the comments as its purely my interpretation. The crew of the prometheus are mistaken in thinking that the engineers want humans to find them for benevolent reasons. They have been breeding biological weapons and would want hosts to incubate them in, i.e. humans. Rather than wait around for us to evolve for a couple million years they leave instructions for us to find them. When the engineer sets course for earth at the end of the film its not to destroy us but to harvest us. It's still a ridiculous film though no matter how you interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/what-is-the-real-purpose-of-the-star-map-in-prometheus) provided by @fez in the comments, we can assume a few possibilities:

### It's a warning

During the movie we discover at one point that the Engineers decided to release one of the weapons upon Earth. One may think they warned humans in a Biblical sense. Almost like a "Behave or die" meaning. But their plans ran into an end early and we managed to find them thousands of years later.

### They never expected humans would go so far

Maybe they planned since the beginning to kill everyone on Earth, way before we were capable of achieving the "Final Frontier", so why bother hiding anything from very primitive life forms?
In this case, they could have expected humans would reach space travel technology sometime, but that wouldn't matter, or they never expected that.

### Testing

The screenplay doesn't make it clear, but they could have created us (Humans), and reaching to an exact point out in the space based on a cave drawing would be a good challenge to validate our own evolution.

### Conclusion

What I want to say, after all of this is that the movie does't answer all the questions it raises, letting us wandering and discussing, so as we can't put ourselves in the place of an extraterrestrial intelligent fictional life form, the best conclusion we will get is: why Humans would or wouldn't do something like that.